# How to get OAuth AccessToken (google) for posting a job to Google Hire in C#?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-indexing-api

I'm trying to post a job at Google Hire. Prerequsites are done as metioned [here](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/prereqs) . I got the service account credentials in a json file.

I tried to get Access Token using :

```
var jsonFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleKey/client_secret.json");


var token = GetAccessTokenFromJSONKey(path,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"); 

public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenFromJSONKeyAsync(string jsonKeyFilePath, params string[] scopes)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonKeyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                return await GoogleCredential
                    .FromStream(stream) // Loads key file  
                    .CreateScoped(scopes) // Gathers scopes requested  
                    .UnderlyingCredential // Gets the credentials  
                    .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(); // Gets the Access Token  
            }

        }


 public static string GetAccessTokenFromJSONKey(string jsonKeyFilePath, params string[] scopes)
        {
            return GetAccessTokenFromJSONKeyAsync(jsonKeyFilePath, scopes).Result;
        }
```

but the problem is after executing the function, it just hangs up/ stops responding. I'm unable to get any value in "token " .

May I know as to where am I doing wrong ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with the google .net client library?   Or manually yourself?

Comment: i just installed 1 nuget package (Google.Apis.Auth).

Comment: you are going to have at least one issue the dll for that api hasnt been built yet we are having an issue with the builder.  [issue 1249](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1249)   I can probably help you get the token back from the service account auth but your going to have to create all the requests yourself or wait until we get the dll built.

Comment: No problem, I ll built the rest of the requests required but for that token is required. Please help me out in getting the token.

Comment: I will find sometime in the morning to make you an example

Comment: Thanks.. Looking forward for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```
var keyFilePath = @"C:\Users\LindaL\Documents\.credentials\ServiceAccount.json";
var clientEmail = "1046123799103-6v9cj8jbub068jgmss54m9gkuk4q2qu8@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
var scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" };

GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
    .CreateScoped(scopes);
    }

var token = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
```

The above code should request a token for you using the idexing api.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This work like a charm. I ve a another doubt that after posting jobs to google hire using indexing api i m getting response as 200 but how to get know that whether it is published or not on their site?How long it will take to reflect?

Comment: no idea its a new API I haven't had time to test it myself

Comment: have tested these APIs. Actually my urls getting indexed but still not published on Google Jobs. Can you please help whom to contact or what to do to get it published?

Comment: might get some help here https://github.com/google/search-samples/issues